# MVC error in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to delete the record of employee using Post Method. I replaced the html.Actionlink with button. I also want to prompt user for confirmation before deleting the record.
I have written following code:

```
<input value="Delete" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete ID = @item.EmpId');"/>
```

This line is showing error "`unterminated string constant`",
what's wrong in this code?

my complete view code

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DID)
        </th>
        <th>Action
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Employee",new{id=item.EmpId}))
        {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmpId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmpId }) |

                <input value="Delete" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete ID = @item.EmpId');"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code of your view? At least the part where @item is defined

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: yes sir , when i remove that javascript code , then there is no error

Comment: perhaps there is no error when you pull out that onclick but since it seems valid maybe something previous to that is causing it to throw an error there.  What does the rendered Edit & Details links look like?  Also are you actually getting your @item.EmpId rendered in your onclick or are the quotes around it keeping it from being processed?

Comment: actually it is because of js quotes

Comment: Is EmpId number or string? Would be great if you could post html dump.

Comment: EmpId is an Int. 
Html Dump ? I didn't get you here

Answer (score -1):

Just run the application.let the error be there. You wont get any error at complile or run time.It will run as expected.